# Remote Desktop - Wait operation timed out

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vpn

I have been connecting to a Windows 7 x64 machine at work via VPN for about 2 years now, 4-6 days a week, multiple times per day, always without issue.

As of today, I am able to connect and am presented with the normal Welcome screen. However, after 5 minutes of waiting, I am presented with this dialog:

[image]

I have tried re-connecting my VPN. I have tried rebooting my laptop. I have also remotely rebooted the remote system using "psshutdown -r" but the result is always the same.

Comment: I experience this occasionaly in Windows 10 when I debug my application using C++ Builder and minimize RDP session window for longer time (at least few minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I physically went to my office and the screen was blanked and I was unable to re-activate the screen (ctrl-alt-del and other various keystrokes to try to "wake" the system). My system had apparently crashed and stuck in some powered-on but locked-up state, but not locked up enough to actually block my RDP connection attempts!

I held the power-switch down for 3 seconds, powered it back on and RDP worked just fine again.

Comment: Same experience here. I was able to confirm that *some* services were still running on the machine, but not enough to permit logon via RDP or at the physical console. I couldn't establish a remote connection via Computer Management in order to view the state of (or start) Windows services. In the end a hard-reboot was the only option.

Comment: I can reboot also by software from remote location. I have installed Tight VNC Server for such emergency situations. I connect to work computer, if needed send Ctrl+Alt+Del combination and reboot by using login screen button.

Answer (score 1):

Same/similar issue and really had to get access to the open programs, hard reset of machine was not an option.

By using `Invoke-Command` I used `taskkill /im:explorer.exe /f` and `taskkill /im:dwm.exe /f`
The later killing "Desktop Window Manager" which allowed login and restarted the process. (Used taskmg to restart explorer.exe)

And so I was able to restore access to a Windows 10 instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. First look at the Event logs.
2. Check your and destination firewall.
3. Use network monitoring to detect where you have delay.

If doesn't work try to remote to other PCs To determine that which PCs have problem.

Comment: Event log had no mention of anything to do with RDP. Firewall service on both systems were (and always were) deactivated. Delay? It takes 5 minutes to time-out, I don't think I am having internet connectivity issues - I have a 10mbps connection at home and 100gps at work, which is physically located 1km from my home. I can also log into other systems at our work.